# Multiple Files upload in spring mvc

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, apache-commons-fileupload

I am trying to upload multiple files using spring mvc and commons-fileupload*.jar. I am using HttpServletRequest for getting the request object and then request.getPart() to get file part. But when I run the code I found below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
```

the code is as below:

```
public ModelAndView uploadCon(@RequestParam Map<String,String> map, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    Part part1=request.getPart("wallpaper0");
    Part part2=request.getPart("wallpaperx");
    //then write these files 
}
```

the spring-servlet.xml file has the bean defined as below:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> handleFileUpload(
        @RequestParam("file1") MultipartFile file1,
        @RequestParam("file2") MultipartFile file2) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("status", "failure");
    try {
        if (!file1.isEmpty() && !file2.isEmpty()) {

            // get the files here

            map.put("status", "success");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.severe(e.toString());
    }

    ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(
            map, HttpStatus.OK);

    return responseEntity;
}
```

and make sure that you have added

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
            <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000"/>
</bean>
```

in your *spring.xml* file.

Or [refer this sample](http://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-tutorial-how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-specific-location/) if you want to get a list of files as `List<MultipartFile>`.

Comment: In the above example we will have every file passed on the form as a name of "file " but In the case I am facing different-2 file name on the form.

Comment: @user2677600 do you want to pass multiple files?

Comment: Thanks... It worked out for me. Above pattern is quiet messy as if we have 10-15 files with different different file size and type and we want to save them as the user required then its not a good way . What I was looking for a short version of RequestParams like we have @RequestParam Map<String,String> can't we do same for MultipartFile.

Comment: @user2677600 I have added a link in the answer please refer it.

Comment: @user2677600 It's my pleasure!